# codeigniter 2 url routing + htaccess weird querystring

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, query-string, codeigniter-2

I have a problem with my Codeigniter routing and hope someone can help. The routing works fine for most part but seems to break when subdomains are involved. I think its to do with the htaccess but im really not sure at all and hoping someone can help.

If I go to `mysite.co.uk/a-page/` this works as expected.

If I go to `subdomain.mysite.co.uk` this also works (I have a separate default_controller loaded for a subdomain).

If someone goes to `subdomain.mysite.co.uk/anything` this 404's as expected.

However if by mistake someone goes to `subdomain.mysite.co.uk/a-page/` this should also 404 but it does not. Instead it changes to the following URL:

```
http://www.subdomain.mysite.co.uk/index.php?/a-page/
```

This then loads the "a-page" function. I want it to 404. The weird thing is the profiler doesnt pick up the URI above. Instead it just think it is "a-page".

In my config I have the following:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '/';
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

I know its not ideal but for the subdomain check I am doing the following at the bottom of my routes.php

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])){
    $currentURL = parse_url('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    $urlHostPieces = explode('.', $currentURL['host']);
    $subdomainValue = $urlHostPieces[1]; // will either be a genuine value or the domain name
}else{
    $subdomainValue = DOMAIN;
}

if($subdomainValue !== DOMAIN){
    //is subdomain
    $route['default_controller'] = "controller/function/$subdomainValue";
} else{
    //everything else
    $route['default_controller'] = "controller/home";
}
```

I am using the htaccess by Fabdrol which seems to be quite common when googling. However I added code for a trailing slash and force www.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    # this adds trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    # Forces WWW
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]  


</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas how I can 404 the weird variations? Also read that the uri_protocol should be chnaged to REQUEST_URI but that didnt affect it either.

Also I thought about checking uri segment. If it exists then just 404 but even with that the segment doesnt exist. Its as if the extra string doesnt even exist as far are CI is concerned.

Hope I haven't missed anything. If you need more example code feel free to say.

Thanks for reading and hope someone can help and explain why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .htaccess file is forcing the url change because of the **#Forces WWW** section, which is causing your sub-domain routing to break. (I'm assuming)

Try changing the lines:

```
# Forces WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To:

```
# Forces WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also, because you are using 301 Redirects (you'll want to change those to R=302 for Dev Environments), you might still be redirected because your browser has cached the 301.  Test on another browser that you haven't used for a few days, or clear your current browsers cache.

**Just took a second glance, and the trailing slash section might also cause you issues with Chrome browser given how many redirects you are already going to be forcing.  I have experienced this before with CI, where adding/removing trailing slash causes Chrome to mark page as possibly malicious

Comment: Thanks for your reply and explanation. I just tried that, only I replaced "subdomain" with .* because the subdomains are dynamic. This sort of worked. It does not have the index.php anymore but still loads the "a-page" method instead of 404'ing. Also will this mean subdomains could cause duplicate issues as Google may cache a www version and one without? thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on Chrome as well. I will test this and see if it plays up :)

Comment: The 'a-page' issue is very bizarre. It might be a caching issue from a previous 301 redirect, so I would try a different browser first, but I don't see anything in your routing or .htaccess files that should be causing this action still.

As for the www caching, if you are intending to use sub-domains, I would recommend forcing no www instead, so that you avoid duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know how I would force no www for wildcard subdomains in the htaccess? I think once I have it down to 1 version of the URL I can do a check to see if it does/ does not exist in the array. Appreciate the help so far!

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Thanks for that, will give it ago :) Appreciate the help.